# Inno Setup GetExceptionMessage returns empty message

Tags: exception, inno-setup, iisvdir

in Inno Setup script GetExceptionMessage returns empty message (it contains only colon ":" sign). The last version of Inno Setup (5.4.2) is used.

```
try
  Log('Create IISNamespace');
  // Create IIS namespace object
  if Length(virtualDirectoryName) > 0 then
  begin
    IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
    Log('Get IIsWebService');
    WebSite := IIS.GetObject('IIsWebService', IISServerName + '/w3svc');
    Log('Get IIsWebServer');
    WebServer := WebSite.GetObject('IIsWebServer', IISServerNumber);
    Log('Get IIsWebVirtualDir');
    WebRoot := WebServer.GetObject('IIsWebVirtualDir', 'Root');
    Log('Delete IIsWebVirtualDir');
    WebRoot.Delete('IIsWebVirtualDir', virtualDirectoryName);
    WebRoot.SetInfo();
  end;
except
  MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:IISException,'+ GetExceptionMessage +'}'),
    mbInformation, mb_Ok);
  Log('Uninstall IIS 6 exception: ' + GetExceptionMessage);
end;
```

The exception occurs during deleting IIsWebVirtualDir.
Is there any way to get exception type or real exception message?

Thanks, Denis.

Comment: If I run the CodeAutomation.iss sample that ships with inno both `GetExceptionMessage`/`ShowExceptionMessage` return ":" so it seems broken; try an older version?

Comment: I also tried 5.2.3 version. The result is the same. The exceptions are working properly in other areas of installer - the messages were shown during other exception events. Possibly the bug is related to OLE/COM operations in inno setup.

Comment: XP SP3, Roberts divide/zero show an error but the script that uses COM shows; `ISS Exception " :  " occured.`

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the following example to see if either `GetExceptionMessage` or `ShowExceptionMessage` are broken.   I used both Inno setup 5.4.2 Unicode and Ansi versions.

```
[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\test

[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
 I: Integer;
begin
 try
  I := I div 0; // Raise an exception 
 except
      MsgBox(GetExceptionMessage,
      mbError, MB_OK);

      ShowExceptionMessage;
 end;
 result := false;
end;
```

I also ran CodeAutomation.iss that ships and it worked as expected.   Which is contrary to the comment made by Alex K. that it may be broken.

Now that I know that the routines should work, I took your code and made the following setup test Script and ran it and it raised an exception on not finding the ISSNamespace as I don't have it installed.

```
[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\test
[CustomMessages]
IISException =ISS Exception " %1 " occured.

[Code]

const
  IISServerName = 'localhost';
  IISServerNumber = '1';
  IISURL = 'http://127.0.0.1';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  IIS, WebSite, WebServer, WebRoot, VDir: Variant;
  virtualDirectoryName : String;
begin
virtualDirectoryName := 'test';
try
  Log('Create IISNamespace');
  // Create IIS namespace object
  if Length(virtualDirectoryName) > 0 then
  begin
    IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
    Log('Get IIsWebService');
    WebSite := IIS.GetObject('IIsWebService', IISServerName + '/w3svc');
    Log('Get IIsWebServer');
    WebServer := WebSite.GetObject('IIsWebServer', IISServerNumber);
    Log('Get IIsWebVirtualDir');
    WebRoot := WebServer.GetObject('IIsWebVirtualDir', 'Root');
    Log('Delete IIsWebVirtualDir');
    WebRoot.Delete('IIsWebVirtualDir', virtualDirectoryName);
    WebRoot.SetInfo();
  end;
except
 MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:IISException,'+ GetExceptionMessage +'}'),
    mbInformation, mb_Ok);
  Log('Uninstall IIS 6 exception: ' + GetExceptionMessage);
end;
end;
```

But I made a fatal flaw during the construction of this script that could be your problem.

Check your `[CustomMesssages]` section make sure you have %1 in the message.  Otherwise nothing is returned.

Comment: Yes, I use "IIS Exception: %1"  message in [CustomMessages] section. Really, empty exception looks like exception processing bug in inno setup.

Comment: @Dennis Is the exception message also blank in the log?   What OS and version of IIS are you running on it may be specific to that?

Comment: Yes, the log message looks like "Uninstall IIS 6 exception: : ". OS/IIS versions: Windows Server 2003/IIS 6.